# Que signifie le mot « signaux » dans ce contexte

Tags: sens, expressions

Bonjour à tous. Que signifie le mot « signaux » dans ce contexte :
« En effet, l'accès aux productions humaines passées et présentes semble
aujourd'hui illimité. Tout se reproduit, objets, sons, documents et le mouvement
même de la vie. Tout se diffuse sans limite de quantité, les objets les plus
périssables traversent le monde et l'on reproduit des signaux extrêmement
complexes avec une précision croissante. » Merci d'avance.

Comment: Je remarque que toutes les questions que tu as posées sur French.SE n'ont pas de réponses sélectionnées. N'hésite pas à choisir la réponse qui convient à tes questions et qui te satisfait en cliquant sur l'encoche en bas des votes ;)

Comment: Ah, je ne l'avais pas remarqué, je le ferai dorénavant. Merci

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il sagit de [signaux électriques](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_%C3%A9lectrique). Ces signaux peuvent être des sons, des images, ou bien d'autres types d'information.

Answer (score 3):

Je crois qu'il s'agit d'une expression métaphorique associant le mot signal, qui peut désigner scientifiquement une onde électromagnétique, à tout document ou objet imaginable, aussi complexe dans sa structure qu'il puisse être.